# Lets Encrypt renew protocol steps

Tags: lets-encrypt, renewal

I have a custom client that i use to get Lets Encrypt certificates but i can't work out the proper protocol to renew the certificates. The versions of the spec that i have found seem very vague on the exact renewal process.

Is the renewal process any different from a new certificate request? Are there steps i can skip or is it totally different?  I am currently using the DNS based verification if that makes a difference. At the minute i am just requesting a new certificate following the full process but i am not sure if that the correct way or over kill or a very bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your client, however, the steps should be similar to the initial request. The difference is that you don't have to regenerate a private key or a CSR if you saved them and your private key did not get compromised.

This makes it very easy to automate the renewal process.

Comment: I can save what ever details i need and it really should not depend on the client when you are talking protocol level.  I am trying to implement the offical protocol if that helps. i assume with your steps it would follow the normal request signing steps  Do you still need to go though the domain verification steps and use the same url and rest api or is it a different api endpoint and api call?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they will be adding automatic renewal scripts in the near future, there is a basic bash script posted on the front page of the website at the moment.